# Automatically put content in for read in bash

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Hi  I have a little bash script and before i used to type the content in a bit like answering a question, but what i would like to do is just run the bash script and instead of answering the question it would just put the answer automatically in.

```
    echo "
Please type in your name "

echo $name > /root/details/name.info
echo "
Your name is $name ! "

echo "
    What is your age "
    read age
    echo $age > /root/details/age.info

echo "
This server will carry out a complete maintenance routine daily
Enter the time at which this routine should happen :
Example : Eleven o'clock is 23 , midnight is 00 , three in the morning is 03 ...
Based on the example , enter the time of maintenance with a decimal number 00-23
Please note: ( 00/23 )"

echo $HorMan>

echo "
    Please enter  your username e.g. admin"
    read username
    echo $username > /root/details/username.info
```

In the above code Name and Age would be different on each script run but Server maintenance and Username would be the same on every script run.

Comment: You're reading in `age` twice...

Answer (score 1):

Put the answers to the questions in a text file, one answer per line, in the correct order.

Then run your script:

```
$ ./script.sh <answers.txt
```

**EDIT**: After updated question.

If some of the input to the script is static, either don't read them in the script at all (replace with static data), or have a second script that fills in those values:

```
$ ./answerscript.sh <answers.txt | ./script.sh
```

The `answers.txt` contains names and ages on alternating lines, while the `answerscript.sh` does the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=
while read name; do
  echo $name
  read age
  echo $age
  echo 23
  echo enoch
done
```

(`23` and `enoch` is the time and the username that is static).

BTW, your script, as it is written now, won't read the name nor the time.

Comment: what if some of the questions needed manual input for example when the script asks for a domain name or email address

Comment: @ChrisJakson This script is deterministic, right? So you know in advance exactly what questions will be asked? In that case, it's just a matter of putting in the right answers in the right order into the `answers.txt` file. As far as I can see, you are using basic `read` calls, and those read from standard input. Doing it this way replaces standard input with input from the file. If this is not what you were asking for, then please update the question.

Comment: Just updated the code

Comment: @ChrisJakson Updated the answer.

Comment: if it's a static entry could i just use a echo command instead of the read command, and if it's a dynamic entry use the read command.

Comment: @ChrisJakson In your script? Yes of course. Replace the `read` with a variable assignment instead.